# How to make ctrl+c /not/ interrupt the while-loop?

Tags: bash

Given this loop:

```
while sleep 10s ; do
  something-that-runs-forever
done
```

When I press Ctrl+C the whole while-loop gets interrupted. What I want to do is to interrupt the "something"-process, let 10 seconds pass, and then restart "something".

How do I make ctrl+c only affect "something", and not the while-loop?

EDIT: "interrupt" as in SIGINT. Kill. Abort. Terminate. Not "interrupt" as in "pause".

Comment: If you just want to pause it, why not use Ctrl+Z, wait 10 seconds and run `fg`? Why use Ctrl+C at all?

Comment: @terdon : Thanks for the comment, may be I rushed in with the answer. Need to read more on OPs requirement

Comment: @terdon: I don't want to pause it. I want 10 seconds to pass, like I wrote.

Comment: You said: `What I want to do is to interrupt the "something"-process, let 10 seconds pass, and then restart "something"`. If you hit Ctrl+Z, wait 10s and then run `fg`, that's exactly what will happen. Maybe you could [edit] your question and give a specific example so we can understand better?

Comment: I thought that in the context of Ctrl+C interrupt was unambiguous, but obviously I was wrong. I have now edited.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should work if you just `trap` `SIGINT` to something. Like `:` (`true`).

```
#!/bin/sh
trap ":" INT    
while sleep 10s ; do
    something-that-runs-forever
done
```

Interrupting the `something...` doesn't make the shell exit now, since it ignores the signal. However, if you ^C the `sleep` process, it will exit with a failure, and the loop stops due to that. Move the `sleep` to the inside of the loop or add something like `|| true` to prevent that.

Note that if you use `trap "" INT` to ignore the signal completely (instead of assigning a command to it), it's also ignored in the child process, so then you can't interrupt `something...` either. This is explicitly mentioned in at least [Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-trap):

> If *arg* is the null string, then the signal specified by each *sigspec* is ignored by the shell and commands it invokes. *[...]*
>   Signals ignored upon entry to the shell cannot be trapped or reset.

Comment: Can this be achieved in the current shell as well? (Not in a script.)

Comment: You might want `do (trap - INT; something-that-runs-forever)` to allow interrupt of the command.  Also, you don't need to run `:` - you can just use an empty string to ignore a signal: `trap '' INT`.  All this is POSIX, and should work on any compliant shell (not just Bash).

Comment: Note also that writing `SIGINT` in full isn't strictly portable: "*Implementations may permit names with the `SIG` prefix or ignore case  in  signal
       names **as an extension**.*" (my emphasis)

Comment: you can pass the empty string as the action to ignore a signal e.g. `trap "" INT` (also posix)

Comment: @TobySpeight, the reason I used `trap :` instead of `trap ""` was exactly that, to _not_ have the signal ignored (but make it a no-op instead), so that we don't need to do anything else to be able to interrupt the main `something` program.

Comment: Bash's manual states that "If *arg* is the null string, then the signal specified by each *sigspec* is ignored by the shell **and commands it invokes**". All the other shells I tried do the same, but I didn't see if that's mentioned in the standard. Of course, you could use `trap "" INT; (trap - INT; something)` if you want

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I missed the significance of "if" (i.e. *and only if*) in the final sentence.  It wasn't obvious that using a command instead of empty string does let the child receive the signal.  Perhaps there's an opportunity to present both `trap : INT` and trap '' INT` and show how they differ?

Comment: @TobySpeight, that's what I tried to explain in the last paragraph... Also, resetting the ignored signal in a subshell doesn't actually work, though I don't know what the underlying mechanic is. Bash's manual says that "Signals ignored upon entry to the shell cannot be trapped or reset."

Comment: This worked for my purpose in zsh: `setopt localtraps ;
    trap "" INT ; 
    (shell-function)`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make `something-that-runs-forever` handle the signal (exiting gracefully when it's received). Of course, it only makes sense to do when this program is used in many scripts, and the desired behavior on <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is systematically the same - to continue script execution.

Comment: ITYM "sleep and re-exec itself", not "exit gracefully"?