# Delay termination of script

Tags: shell-script, signals, openbsd, trap

I have a script like this (written for `/bin/sh` on OpenBSD) which first updates a local copy of some CVS repositories using `rsync`, and then updates the checked-out version of these on my machine.  The script is run as root through OpenBSD's [`doas`](http://man.openbsd.org/doas) (a `sudo` "equivalent" on OpenBSD):

```
#!/bin/sh

int_handler () {
    echo 'Wait...' >&2
    quit=1
}

quit=0
trap int_handler INT

for r in CVSROOT src xenocara ports; do
    su cvsuser -c 'rsync --archive --itemize-changes --delete --omit-dir-times \
        "rsync://anoncvs.eu.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-cvs/$r/" \
        "/extra/cvs/$r/"'
done

trap - INT

[ "$quit" -eq 1 ] && exit

# rest of script updates checked-out CVS repositories from local copy
```

The idea is that I may press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> while the `rsync` loop is running to later skip the second part of the script (which I may not always want to run, depending on what has been updated in the repositories) without interrupting the loop and its `su`+`rsync` processes.

This does not work and the `rsync` process receives the signal and terminates (and the next iteration of the `for` loop continues).  `rsync` says (when pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> multiple times until the script terminates):

```
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(642) [generator=3.1.3]
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at io.c(504) [receiver=3.1.3]
Wait...
rsync: [receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at io.c(1633) [sender=3.1.3]
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(642) [generator=3.1.3]rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at io.c(504) [receiver=3.1.3
]

rsync: [receiver] write error: Broken pipe (32)
Wait...
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(642) [generator=3.1.3]
rsync error: received SIGUSR1 (code 19) at main.c(1440) [receiver=3.1.3]
Wait...
```

According to an answer to the question "[How to make ctrl+c /not/ interrupt the while-loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419026)", at least when running `bash`, one should be able to *ignore* the `INT` signal, which will make child processes also ignore that signal.  This is not ideal, but I'd be happy to try.

So, second try in the light of that:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

trap '' INT

for r in CVSROOT src xenocara ports; do
    su cvsuser -c 'rsync --archive --itemize-changes --delete --omit-dir-times \
        "rsync://anoncvs.eu.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-cvs/$r/" \
        "/extra/cvs/$r/"'
done

trap - INT

read -p 'Press enter or interrupt...' junk

# rest of script updates checked-out CVS repositories from local copy
```

This likewise allows the `rsync` process to be interrupted by <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Ok, so maybe it's the `su` that resets the signal mask?  A third try:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

trap '' INT

for r in CVSROOT src xenocara ports; do
    su -s /usr/local/bin/bash cvsuser -c \
        'trap "" INT; rsync --archive --itemize-changes --delete --omit-dir-times \
        "rsync://anoncvs.eu.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-cvs/$r/" \
        "/extra/cvs/$r/"'
done

trap - INT

read -p 'Press enter or interrupt...' junk

# rest of script updates checked-out CVS repositories from local copy
```

Nope, no joy.  The `rsync` process is *still* interruptible in the same way.

Is there a way to get the script working the way I (initially) intended?

`bash` on my machine is release 4.4.23.  The `/bin/sh` is the native `pdksh` variant on OpenBSD running in POSIX mode.

Comment: Related - While looking for the same Q, I came into the same solution as Stephane posted on the other SE sites - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570680/bash-trap-wont-ignore-signal/51256203#51256203 & https://serverfault.com/questions/706238/bash-rsync-is-killed-by-signal-2/920204#920204.

Answer (score 5):

So, since you don't really want an interrupt, how about disabling it on the terminal level, with `stty intr ""`? That would make the `^C` appear in the input buffer as any ordinary character, and we can read it from there.

This works for me on Linux:

```
#!/bin/bash

t=$(stty -g)
stty intr ""
echo please hold
sleep 5
stty "$t"

# short timeout, just check if there was any input earlier
read -n1 -t0.1 a
[[ "$a" = $'\003' ]] && echo "you hit ^C"
```

(I can't test on OpenBSD, but I suppose the terminal setup stuff is standard.)

Comment: This works. It's just unfortunate that I'd have to use `bash` to do it (catching the `^C` at the end). But, when testing, it seems as if I can use a plain `read stuff` and then compare with `if [ "$stuff" = '^C' ]` where `^C` is a literal Ctrl+C inserted with Ctrl+V Ctrl+C in Vim. So, that works.

Comment: But then again, I could just have fed any predetermined string into the terminal (not just `^C`), read it after the loop and quit conditionally. So that kinda makes the `stty` exercise unnecessary in a sense.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yeah, and this can't give feedback for the `^C` immediately (like your `Wait...` message). Having `read -t` would be useful though, even if you do change the skip key to enter instead.

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` installs a handler on SIGINT even if SIGINT was ignored upon start. So if you don't want `^C` to stop rsync (I'd hate that myself as I hate it when the emergency button does not work), you'd have to make sure SIGINT is not delivered to `rsync`.

So either tell the terminal driver not to send a SIGINT to the foreground process group upon `^C` like in [@ikkachu's answer](/a/450140), or put the process running that `rsync` command out of the foreground process group.

Like everything related to signal handling, whether that works or not varies from shell to shell (and the version thereof sometimes).

Your best bet is stick with a known implementation which you know works and hope it will still work in newer versions in a few years time. Like with `zsh`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env zsh

# enable job control (run pipelines in different process groups)
set -o monitor

interrupted() false
trap 'echo Wait...; interrupted() true' INT

# run in background so it won't get the SIGINT upon ^C
# as it won't be in the foreground process group. Note that with
# version 5.1.1 at least, running it without & will also run in
# in a new process group, and not make it the foreground process
# group of the terminal as the shell is not interactive. However
# the trap would be run asynchronously.
rsync... &

while (($#jobstates)) {wait}

interrupted && exit

echo rest of the script
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you could use the command `setsid` to run the rsync in a separate session. OpenBSD does not seem to have this as a command, though the system call exists. You could write your own C version of the command, or try this bit of perl if you have it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(setsid);
POSIX::setsid();
exec @ARGV;
```

If you name this script `mysetsid` you would use it as a prefix to the `su` command, eg: `./mysetsid su cvsuser ...` in the first version of your script. Note, the interrupt is only seen by the handler function once the current rsync command finishes.

Comment: https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/setsid.c is what I use on macOS and OpenBSD

Answer (score 1):

#### Bash implementation

It's pretty clear from experimentation that `rsync` behaves like other tools such as `ping` and dodx not inherit signals from the calling Bash parent.

So you have to get a little creative with this and do something like the following:

```
$ cat rsync.bash
#!/bin/sh

 set -m
 trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
 rsync -avz LargeTestFile.500M root@host.mydom.com:/tmp/. &
 wait

 echo FIN
```

Now when I run it:

```
$ ./rsync.bash
X11 forwarding request failed
building file list ... done
LargeTestFile.500M
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
sent 509984 bytes  received 42 bytes  92732.00 bytes/sec
total size is 524288000  speedup is 1027.96
FIN
```

And we can see the file did fully transfer:

```
$ ll -h | grep Large
-rw-------. 1  501 games 500M Jul  9 21:44 LargeTestFile.500M
```

#### How it works

The trick here is we're telling Bash via `set -m` to disable job controls on any background jobs within it. We're then backgrounding the `rsync` and then running a `wait` command which will wait on the last run command, `rsync`, until it's complete.

We then guard the entire script with the `trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT`.

#### References

- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/360713
- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1539283

Comment: This should work in any `sh`, right? Not just `bash`.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I don't know much about `zsh`, the switching for the `set -m` is different, but otherwise I believe the approach is pretty darn close to Stephane's. I would accept his answer of the ones here, IMO. BTW, I had to do all the SIGs I showed, doing just INT wasn't sufficient.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I thought of merging them, but I generally don't like to do that to his or Gilles' just out of hand.